# Vim Directory Completion

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I like Vim's Directory Completion when I'm normal mode, for example I do something like `:cd ~/Desktop` it actually autocompletes the name When I hit tab.

So here's my question is there something like let's see, I want somefile.png that's stored in my images directory, and I'm operating from my css file, So I type `../img/som` and it automagically completes it for me, is there something like that on ViM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When in Vim insert mode, is there a way to add filepath autocompletion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919492/when-in-vim-insert-mode-is-there-a-way-to-add-filepath-autocompletion)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> while editing will do the job

Comment: This is really super cool, but does not work when there is no space before the path, e.g. in a shell variable assignation `PATH=$HOME/foo`